# How are military aircraft directed to targets?

Tags: military, radar

How would a controller, say, AWACS or ground radar, direct via voice an aircraft to the location of an airborne target?

I've seen it in movies, but don't know if they where right, nor did I understand it.

Comment: At least for ground targets, the 9-Line system is used. This describes the target’s location in coordinates, the approach and departure directions, the target’s description, the munition to use, and maybe some other info. Air controlling may be similar?

Answer (score 1):

The controller has radar ID of both aircraft. The radar display used is 'smart' in that it can plot the direction and speed of flight of the target and attack aircraft. It then is a simple matter to direct the attacker on a course to intercept the target.  At least that is how I did it, once.

Comment: I figured such but was looking for terminology like how the bearings are stated.